# Prove if $A \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb F)$ is both symmetric and skew-symmetric then $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove if $A \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb F)$ is both symmetric and skew-symmetric then $A=0$

I know $A^T = A = -A \Rightarrow A = -A \Rightarrow A_{i,j} = -A_{i,j}$.

Since $\mathbb F$ is a field we have $2A_{i,j} = 0 \Rightarrow 2 = 0 \lor A_{i,j} = 0$.

However how can I verify $A_{i,j} = 0$ ? Suppose $\mathbb F = \{[0],[1]\}$. Then $2 = 0$, so I cannot conclude $A_{i,j} = 0$ ?

Comment: You're exactly right. This holds in every case but characteristic 2. To see this, $A=-A\implies 2A=0$, and that is true for every matrix in characteristic 2. All you need is an explicit example to prove that a nonzero $A$ exists, e.g. the identity.

Comment: In case $\mathbb F = \{[0],[1]\}$ you may only need to look at the Identity matrix as a counter example.

Comment: @IanColey Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 5):

[from my comment]

You're exactly right. This holds in every case but characteristic $2$. To see this, $A=−A\implies2A=0$, and that is true for every matrix in characteristic $2$. All you need is an explicit example to prove that a nonzero $A$ exists, e.g. the identity.